# How to maintain User-session with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Hey folks, I would like to know is there any way i can maintain stuffs like log-in,log-out,user-session..etc without using membership in ASP.NET MVC?

Faraaz.

Comment: try using `FormsAuthentication` or write your own session management.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need to use the Session dictionary and a session state server. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx for more info.

Word of warning: In my experience the InProc session state mode only preserves the values you put into Session for the lifetime of the current HTTP request. They don't persist across requests as you might expect, even when you're using a single HTTP server and you'd think in-memory storage would persist. This may only occur while debugging using the built-in http server in VS2010, but even so it can cause you a lot of trouble trying to understand why state information isn't being saved.

Comment: InProc session state persists for the lifetime of the application process (or until cleared) as it is stored in the address space of the process. If the application is recycled then you will lose session.

Comment: Thanks Doug, Wat about authentication/authorization??

Comment: @Russ: that's what the documentation states, but it's not what I experienced which is why I gave a warning. There might be a difference between IIS and the built-in server in VS 2010, where the latter only has per-request persistance while the former has per-process persistance. If so, that makes debugging and testing unreliable. In any case, InProc is not scalable: as soon as you need more than one server, you're going to need an external place to store state.

Comment: @nfa379: I've always dealt with situations where I need to authenticate against an existing system. Typically that means checking for and validating a session cookie on every request. If the cookie isn't present or is tied to a non-existent session, send the user to a login view. Perform login using the existing system's api (whatever that may be) and set a new cookie. Ideally, the existing system will generate a token suitable for use in the cookie, and will have an api for verifying the token in future requests. The token should also tie to any authorization info you need.

Comment: @Doug- I have to be honest and say that I've never experienced that using either Cassini, IIS Express and IIS 5,6 and 7. Maybe edit your warning to state that you've experienced per request issues with InProc? I do agree that InProc doesn't scale and I've steered clear of it in a production app for the simple fact that session is lost if the app pool is recycled, something you don't want to happen while performing updates to an app. At the very least I'd recommend State Server, even if the process is still on the same server.

Comment: As @RussCam mentioned, this answer is not accurate.  Session persists for the lifetime of the application until the session expires from the server. The Items collection of the HttpRequest only exists for a single request.  Session state in ASP.NET can only be scalable when not InProc (using SQL Server, State Server, or a custom provider, like AppFabric Caching).

Answer (score 7):

There are three provider models concerned with the areas that you are referring to.

The [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) is concerned with authentication, validating users and storing data related to the user such as last login date, username, etc.

The [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx) is concerned with authorising users for particular areas of your application.

The [SessionStateProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx) is concerned with storing session for your application.

You can write your own custom provider for any of them if the default providers are not suitable. You could roll your own authentication, authorisation, or session management without the providers, however there would be quite a bit of work involved more so than implementing your own custom provider.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Session` object to store session scoped data.

But for authentication/authorization you will need to come up with your own scheme.

Comment: Thanks Oded, I have used Session objet with an ASp.NET app. was just skeptical if it would work for a ASp.NET MVC model.

Comment: Also, do u have working example/link where authentication/authorization is done without membership for asp.net mvc?

Comment: @nfa379 - Nothing off the top of my head. Google is your friend, though I don't know why you have to reinvent the wheel when membership would work.

Comment: Now thats a good qn;) Just thought membership/role is just too complex to go to for a simple app. Thanks anyway:)

Comment: @nfa379- with the providers, you only need implement the methods that you actually want to use.