# javascript validation value from one cshtml page to check other cshtml page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm want to validate value of `name` from `Create.cshtml` and `AddUser.cshtml` page.
working in `mvc application`

in create.cshtml

```
<div id="tab3" class="tab_content">

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstTripStartTime, new { id = "minStartTime", @class = "smallTxtEntry3" })&nbsp;(HH:MM:SS)

</div>
```

in adduser.cshtml

```
<div>
  <td valign="top" class="nd_nor_ftd">Start Time<span class="mand">*</span></td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.StartTime, new { @class = "smallTxtEntry3" })&nbsp;(HH:MM:SS)
                    </td>
</div>
```

How do I compare and show alert if these two values are same

2nd page is in tabular for actually after 1st gets filled.

```
  <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
   <div class="buttonDiv">
      <input type="button" class="button addButton" name="AddUser" id="AddUser" value="Add Useronclick="OpenAddDialogWindow(GoodReceiptParameterCss, '/User/GetPartialView?name=User&mode=add', 'gridVariableFrequencies');" /><br />
       <span>Add Frequency</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MVC [Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138872/how-to-use-sessions-in-an-asp-net-mvc-4-application) object to persist server side data (without the need for a database, or relying on client side storage) and check the values client or server side.

Answer (score 1):

As you are talking about different pages, you can share state and values between them in*at least* 2 ways:

1. Save data in DB from one page and read from another (not so good, as need a request)
2. Save in local storage a value from one page and read it from another page (definitely better)

For easy data save/read on client side can have  look on: [amplify.js](http://amplifyjs.com/).