# create SESSION varables in asp.net mvc4 at controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session

I need to create session variables in controller with data which is sent from the view, and I need to access those session variables in anywhere in my aplication

here is my code

**controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AccessLogInData(Login userloginData)
    {
        string Id = userloginData.Id;
        string userName = userloginData.userName;
        string password = userloginData.password;
        string Designation = userloginData.Designation;
        string Supplier_Code = userloginData.Supplier_Code;
        string Distributor_Code = userloginData.Distributor_Code;
        string Staff_Code = userloginData.Staff_Code;

       //here I need create sessions
    }
```

Comment: To add something to Session - `Session["YourKey"] = yourValue;`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke how can I access session, and do I need start session or something, please explain me little

Comment: To access it - `var value = Session["YourKey"] as yourValueType;`. To clear it - `Session["YourKey"] = null;`

Comment: Suggest you read the answers and comments to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138872/how-to-use-sessions-in-an-asp-net-mvc-4-application)

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke how can I clear whole session varables at once