# Passing model through a page to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We have a job application that uses a two step process.  I need to tweak this slightly.  The easiest way I can see doing this is removing the application creation stage from step one, and just passing it to step two which is a separate view.

**Page 1 - Step 1**

```
public ActionResult Apply(JobApplicant jobapp, string HiddenJobId)
        {
            jobapp.JobID = Convert.ToInt32(HiddenJobId);
            //JobsHelper.CreateJobApplicant(jobapp);

            return View("ApplyResume", jobapp); 
        }
```

The above code used to `CreateJopApplication()`.  I commented this out and am now passing this to the next step/page.

However once on this new page I then have an `[HttpPost]` that takes that `jobapp` but at this point it is all null.

The jobapp(JobApplication) is about 140 columns, I'd hate to have to create a hidden text field for all of that.  Is there an easier way to pass a model across two pages?

**Step 2 - Page 2**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, string applicantId, string coverLetter, JobApplicant jobapp)
        {
            // jobapp is null during this entire step, passed in null its as if the page before never had it.
            JobsHelper.CreateJobApplicant(jobapp);
            .......
```

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138872/how-to-use-sessions-in-an-asp-net-mvc-4-application)

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you *need* two steps? Seems silly to me to have a user fill out 140 fields and then take them to another step just to upload something. Just add the upload to the same initial step.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Other than that is how it was originally designed nope.  If working from scratch I would have designed it all on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use `TempData`. It is like a session state but it's removed once it gets used. It is good for one round trip.

With a stateless framework like MVC, you can:

- Persist inside the form using hidden fields
- Persist in database
- Persist in session state or temporary state

Comment: TempData did not work, but using a session variable did.