# How to initialize field once for every client in MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC, a field which is declare outside a method, the field is initialize every-time.

There I am giving a demo example.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{

    private List<object> ListItems; 
    // GET: /Test/Index
    public ActionResult Index(int Id)
    {
        ModelSource _model = new ModelSource(Id);
        ListItems = _model.GetItems();//coming info from Model
        return View();
    }


    // GET: /Test/Demo
    public ActionResult Demo()
    {
        int x  = ListItems.Count;
        //Do Something More
        return View(x);
    }
}
```

Is It possible for `ListItems` will be initialize for once for every client as `Id` parameter will be different on client's request.

Comment: Save it in the `Session`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, First, Thanks for the reply, Can you give me some reference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14138872/993547

Comment: @PatrickHofman, It works, Thanks you very much. 
You saved my rest of times :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Patrick Hofman stated you can use `Sessions` or `Cookies` Here is an example for both:

**Cookies:**

```
 string cookievalue ;
 if ( Request.Cookies["cookie"] != null )
 {
    cookievalue = Request.Cookies["cookie"].ToString();
 }
 else
 {
    Response.Cookies["cookie"].Value = "cookie value";
 }
//For removing cookie use following code

if (Request.Cookies["cookie"] != null)
{
    Response.Cookies["cookie"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);   
}
```

**Sessions:**

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("Title", "Data"); 

string foo = Session["Title"];
```

Comment: @RitwickDey glad it did =)