# How can I remove a record from List

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

How can I remove a record from List in MVC 4 ASP.NET by click on Delete button Here I am not using any database I want to delete a record from list which I have define in controller. without any database remove a record from list using delete action

**StudentController**

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Student/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<StudentVM> students = new List<StudentVM>();
        StudentVM obj1 = new StudentVM();
        obj1.Name = "Zeeshan";
        obj1.id = "1";
        obj1.Address = "Lahore";

        students.Add(obj1);


        StudentVM obj2 = new StudentVM();
        obj2.Name = "Zeshan";
        obj2.id = "2";
        obj2.Address = "Lahore";

        students.Add(obj2);
        return View(students);
    }

    public ActionResult Delete(string? i)
    {
        List<StudentVM> students = new List<StudentVM>();

        var st = students.Find(c => c.id = i);
        students.Remove(st);
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model List<Activity2.Models.StudentVM>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var obj in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@obj.id</td>
            <td>@obj.Name</td>
            <td>@obj.Address</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete","Delete",new{i = obj.id}) </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    }
```

**Error**

> Error 1 The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order
>   to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'System.Nullable'
>       Error 3   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string?' to 'string'

Comment: Can you talk us through why you **don't** want to use a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use nullable reference-types which is a feature of C# 8.0 (which hasn't been released **yet**). In order to fix your errors you'd have to change your `string? i` to `string i`.

To remove items from the list you'd have to create it outside of your `Index()` and make it static, so other Endpoints like `Delete()` are able to access the list. That way each time somebody accesses the Index of your Controller two new students are added to the List (probably not the behavior you'd want in the long run, i just copied your code on this one):

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    private static readonly List<StudentVM> _students = new List<StudentVM>();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        StudentVM obj1 = new StudentVM();
        obj1.Name = "Zeeshan";
        obj1.id = "1";
        obj1.Address = "Lahore";

        _students.Add(obj1);

        StudentVM obj2 = new StudentVM();
        obj2.Name = "Zeshan";
        obj2.id = "2";
        obj2.Address = "Lahore";

        _students.Add(obj2);

        return View(students);
    }

    public ActionResult Delete(string i)
    {
        var student = _students.FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == i);

        if(student == null){ /* Failed to find student */ }

        _students.Remove(student);
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

Also there seems to be an Error in your View code. The `</table>` should be outside of the foreach.

Comment: i  have try your code this error come 1. ``Error 1 The name 'students' does not exist in the current context 
Error 2 Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<Activity2.Models.StudentVM,bool>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type 
Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' ``

Comment: @rajpootrana the snippet i posted shouldn't have such an error. Where are you getting it?

Comment: the error is because of id this error comes  here  ``var student = _students.FirstOrDefault(c => c.id = i);``  Error  Can not implicitly convert type from 'string' to 'bool'

Comment: @rajpootrana Wupps, i copied it wrong from your code. It needs to be `var student = _students.FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == i);`. Now everything should work. If it does please mark this answer as the answer so others know the problem is solved.

Comment: NullReference Exception was unhandle by user code   ``@foreach (var obj in Model)``

Comment: @rajpootrana this Exception has nothing todo with the question you've asked. Please mark my answer as the question as it likely solves the question you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as the error message is clearly saying you need to use `string` instead of `string?`:

```
public ActionResult Delete(string i)
```

And secondly you should be aware that, MVC is **stateless** because HTTP is. So this code won't delete the record as per your expectation. In order to make this code works, you need to use [**Session**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138872/how-to-use-sessions-in-an-asp-net-mvc-4-application). Something like this:

```
if(Session["StudentVM"] == null)
{
    //Your Code
     Session["StudentVM"] = students;
}
```

And:

```
public ActionResult Delete(string i)
{
    List<StudentVM> students = Session["StudentVM"] as List<StudentVM>;
    var st = students.Find(c=>c.id=i);
    //The rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: Sir if you have a right code foe how to delete a record from list  in MVC asp.net without database please share with me...

Comment: @rajpootrana The code that I have shown to you in my answer, is right. You just need to try it!