# How can I get AD User information AND check for group membership Globally

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to set a variable globally that has the AD Username and emails address and check status if the logged in user is a member of a certain group. I can do this via a controller - but I would like to be able to have a global variable that works for all views. Is this possible?

Thanks,
EB

Comment: Why would user-specific information be globally available?

Comment: [Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138872/how-to-use-sessions-in-an-asp-net-mvc-4-application)

Comment: When a user opens the intranet site I want to set some variables that are always available regardless of what view I am in. Will sessions do this? I do have a session setup in my main controller but I don't this this session is always available?

Comment: @EBaze, depends what you mean by "always". It will be available until user closes the browser, or in whatever time session expires

Comment: @Andrei  - Perfect. Thanks!!

Comment: @User.Identity.Name if you are using AD