# Methods of Session Maintenance in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

me and my team are working on MVC4 based project, and currently working on authentication/session maintenance module.

I just want a list of approaches that can be employed to implement session management in MVC4. After studying pros and cons we will finalize the best suitable one.

I apologize if this question is already answered on StackOverflow, at least I couldn't find much helpful information, so creating this question.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14139064/2186023, http://stackoverflow.com/q/5769219/2186023, http://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/ for starters ;)

Comment: Unfortunately this question is not well suited for stackoverflow, maybe http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is the right place for such a thing. stackoverflow is about solving and getting rid of errors in code (that require already existing code to be posted as well) so since you don't have any code, stackoverflow is not the place.

Comment: Ideally, you want your server code to be stateless.  If you do have to manage state, let the client do so and send up any necessary data to the server with each request.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste: Thanks for those links and sorry for asking the question here, I'll keep that in mind next time.